# Angular2 form custom validation directive

Tags: angular, validation, directive

I'm trying to implement a reactive form using Angular 2 and I have some problems with custom validator.

I'm trying to make a date field valid if the value of the input field is between the (minDate) and (maxDate) attributes of the input field. If one of the previous values is not provided, the no restriction on the min and max constraint.

The problem is that when the "**start_date**" field is modified. The "**start_date**" field validator is triggered (the behavior is ok), but the validator of "**end_date**" field is not triggered despite the (maxDate) attribute change. I can see that because the "**ngOnChanges**" method of directive is called.

Do you have any idea where i'm wrong ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

here is my code:

Component:

```
this.task = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  start_date: ['', Validators.required],
  end_date: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

Vue:

```
<form [formGroup]="task" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>

<label for="name"><b>Name</b>: </label>
  <input id="name" name="name" formControlName="name"/><br>

<label for="start_date"><b>Start</b>: </label>
  <input id="start_date" name="start_date" formControlName="start_date" 
   [maxDate]="task.get('end_date').value"
   appDateValidator/><br>

<label for="end_date"><b>End</b>: </label>
  <input id="end_date" name="end_date" formControlName="end_date"
  [minDate]="task.get('start_date').value"
   appDateValidator/><br>

</form>
```

Directive/Validator:

```
@Directive({
 selector: '[appDateValidator]',
 providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: DateValidatorDirective, multi: true }]
})
export class DateValidatorDirective implements Validator, OnChanges {

  @Input() minDate: string;
  @Input() maxDate: string;
  private valFn = Validators.nullValidator;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    const minDateChange = changes['minDate'];
    const maxDateChange = changes['maxDate'];
    if (minDateChange) {
      this.minDate = minDateChange.currentValue;
    }
    if (maxDateChange) {
      this.maxDate = maxDateChange.currentValue;
    }
    this.valFn = DateValidator(this.minDate, this.maxDate);
  }

  validate(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
    return this.valFn(c);
  }
}

export function DateValidator(minDate: string, maxDate: string): ValidatorFn {
  return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
  let errors = null;

  const dateValueMoment = moment.utc(c.value, moment.ISO_8601);
  const minDateMoment = minDate ? moment.utc(minDate, moment.ISO_8601) : moment.invalid();
  const maxDateMoment = maxDate ? moment.utc(maxDate, moment.ISO_8601) : moment.invalid();
  if (!dateValueMoment.isValid()) {
    errors = Object.assign({}, errors, {
      'value': c.value
    });
  }
  if (minDateMoment.isValid() && dateValueMoment.isBefore(minDate)) {
    errors = Object.assign({}, errors, {
      'min': minDate
    });
  }
  if (maxDateMoment.isValid() && dateValueMoment.isAfter(maxDate)) {
    errors = Object.assign({}, errors, {
      'max': maxDate
    });
  }

  return errors;
  };
}
```

Comment: You have two independent of each other directive instances

Comment: Hi, indeed, but in each directive I have referenced using "minDate" and "maxDate" the other field.  For example, if I change the "start_date" field, I can see that the validator of "start date" is executed thanks to a "console.log" in the validate method. I can also see that "minDate" of "end_date" field is updated (console.log in the ngOnChanges) but unfortunately the validator of "end_date" is not triggered to revalidate.